# Nested ng-repeat with attribute from parent ng-repeat

Tags: json, angularjs, loops

I have a JSON object (`tbls`) which contains an array called `sections`. This array contains titles (`n`) and IDs (`viewid`) of "rooms" that are also a part of the JSON object. This means you can do `tbls.[roomid]` and get the array that contains the objects of each room. I have a hard time making this work in Angular.

It was built this way because it makes it easy to work with when it comes to UITableViews in iOS (where it's implemented and works). Therefore I cannot change the data. I tried below solution, but that gives me an error. Is there an effective way to do this in Angular?

```
<tbody data-ng-repeat="section in tbls.sections">
    <tr>
        <td>{{::section.n}}</td>
    </tr>

    <tr data-ng-repeat="table in tbls.{{section.viewid}}">
        <td>{{::table.n}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

JSON JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lu2ocqku/
Edit: removed tableObj as it's not relevant to the question and doesn't match data example exactly. Same logical problem though.

Edit: Since I asked this question I have changed it to be properly nested with an array of sections containing what is in that section as well. Don't do what I did in this question, originally.

Comment: Can you please give us a sample json, it will make it easier to understand and try it on jsfiddle

Comment: should be `table in section.propertyName`. Show data structure, not clear what your inner loop should be

Comment: just use `[]` object syntax .... `table in tbls[section.viewid]`. Data structure is strane to say the least

Comment: That worked. Put it as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Data structure is "strange" because it's easy to implement sections in Objective-C Table Views when it looks like that, which is where it was first used. But using bracket syntax solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use standard `[]` javascript object syntax:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="table in tbls[section.viewid]">
```